# mPDF TTC font collection

Tags: php, mpdf

I've got Avenir.ttc which has 12 styles from Book, Roman, Medium, Black, etc.

I need the Black style but can only access the Roman, I guess.

The PHP Code:

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf([
    'mode' => 'utf-8',
    'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
        __DIR__ . '/../pdf-template',
    ]),
    'fontdata' => $fontData + [
            // 'avenir' => [
            //  'R' => 'Avenir.ttc',
            //  'B' => 'Avenir.ttc',
            //  'TTCfontID' => [
            //      'R' => 1,
            //      'B' => 7,
            //  ],
            // ],
            'avenirblack' => [
                'R' => 'Avenir.ttc',
                'B' => 'Avenir.ttc',
                'I' => 'Avenir.ttc',
                'TTCfontID' => [
                    'R' => 1,
                    'B' => 2,
                    'I' => 3,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    'default_font' => 'avenirblack',
]);
```

I tried every ordinal number next to R and B, removed some, but cannot get the bold font style of the TTC file.
Demo code in /mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/FontVariables.php looks the same. Any idea what is wrong?

There is no change, when I change font-weight: 100 or 600 or 900 etc. in CSS.